# In R Matching variables in one data set to another data set for if else binned variables

Tags: r, loops, variables, if-statement, matching

I am trying to Bin some (75) continuous variable based on some predefined bins of another data frame. For example, the data frame, G, has all of the bins I want, and the data frame Test is where the continuous variables are that I need to be discreet. For example, the variable, X3975, has bin cut off points  .0625, and .1 so I need to write an ifelse statement like the following:

```
Ifelse((X3975 >=0 & X3975 <=.0625),”0-.0625”,
Ifelse((X3975 >=.0625 & X3975 <=.1),”.0625-.1”,
Ifelse((X3975 >= .1 ),”>.1”,
```

For each of the variables in the G data set to match with the variables in the Test data set. Is there an efficient way of doing this??

G dataframe data set looks like:

```
Bins   Variable
```

1. .0625  X3975
2. .1     X3975
3. .01    X3976
4. .1     X3976
   ......
   a total of 75 different variables with different number of bins

Test dataframe dataset

X3001  X3100  X3102 .... X3999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `cut`

```
lst <- split(G$Bins, G$Variable)
df2 <- df1
df2[] <- Map(function(x,y) cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf,y,Inf)), df1, lst[names(df1)])

df2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X3001 = c(14, 14, NA, 10, 3, 5), X3100 = c(23, 
7, NA, 24, 7, 6), X3102 = c(1, 1, NA, 3, 0, 1), X3104 = c(0, 
0, NA, 2, 0, 0), X3109 = c(1, 1, NA, 7, 1, 1), X3111 = c(197, 
71, NA, 90, 177, 88), X3113 = c(37, 48, NA, 86, NA, 52), X3116 = c(197, 
71, NA, 76, 177, 88), X117 = c(197, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
.Names = c("X3001", 
"X3100", "X3102", "X3104", "X3109", "X3111", "X3113", "X3116", 
"X117"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

G <- structure(list(Bins = c(0, 7, 12, 0, 12, 22, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 
6, 40, 150, 200, 10, 40, 90, 60, 180, 80, 180), Variable = c("X3001", 
"X3001", "X3001", "X3100", "X3100", "X3100", "X3102", "X3102", 
"X3102", "X3104", "X3104", "X3109", "X3109", "X3111", "X3111", 
"X3111", "X3113", "X3113", "X3113", "X3116", "X3116", "X117", 
"X117")), .Names = c("Bins", "Variable"), row.names = c(NA, -23L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is great and certainly gets me close!!! However, my lowest value in the G dataset is, zero, and the highest is 880000. Is there a way instead of the breaks being -Inf to Inf say from zero to 880000?? I REALLY appreciate this help!!! You are saving me a ton of time!!

Comment: @JoseMelendez  You can change ithe `-Inf, Inf` to `0, 880000` or may be `0-0.0001 and 880000+0.1` (not tested though)

Comment: the 0 to 880000 cuts did not works, it gave an error of saying the breaks are not unique but the other way did the trick!!! I really appreciate it!